# How to broker secure connection across firewalls using untrusted host?

Tags: security, networking, ssl, oauth, openssl

I have an interesting network security challenge that I can't figure out the best way to attack.

I need to provide a way to allow two computers (A and B) that are behind firewalls to make a secure connection to each other using only a common "broker" untrusted server on the internet (somewhere like RackSpace). (the server is considered untrusted because the customers behind the firewalls won't trust it since it is on an open server) I can not adjust the firewall settings to allow the networks to directly connect to each other because the connections are no known ahead of time.

This is very similar to a NAT to NAT connection problem like that handled by remote desktop help tools (crossloop, copilot, etc).

What I would really like to find is a way to open an SSL connection between the two hosts and have the public server broker the connection.  Preferably when host A tries to connect to host B, it should have to provide a token that the broker can check with host B before establishing the connection.

To add another wrinkle to this, the connection mechanism needs to support two types of communication.  First, HTTP request/response to a REST web service and second persistent socket connection(s) to allow for real-time message passing.

I have looked at the techniques I know about like OpenSSL using certificates, OAuth, etc, but I don't see anything that quite does what I need.

Has anyone else handled something like this before?  Any pointers?

Comment: You need to pay special attention to the verification of the other party, as the untrusted host is forwarding your traffic...somewhere, which may or may not be your intended destination.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem with plain SSL.

Just have the untrusted server forward connections between the client hosts as opaque TCP connections.  The clients then establish an end-to-end SSL connection over that forwarded TCP tunnel - with OpenSSL, one client calls `SSL_accept()` and the other calls `SSL_connect()`.

Use certificates, probably including client certificates, to verify that the other end of the SSL connection is who you expect it to be.

(This is conceptually similar to the way that HTTPS connections work over web proxies - the browser just says "connect me to this destination", and establishes an SSL connection with the desired endpoint.  The proxy just forwards encrypted SSL data backwards and forwards, and since it doesn't have the private key for the right certificate, it can't impersonate the desired endpoint).

Answer (score 1):

In general, SSL is packet-based protocol (for the purpose of solving your task). If you can have the host forward the packets back and forth, you can easily have SSL-secured communication channel. One thing you need is something like our [SSL/TLS components](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-ssl.php), which allow any transport and not just sockets. I.e. the component tells your code "send this packet to the other side" or "do you have anything for me to receive?" and your code communicates with your intermediate server.

Comment: I was hoping not to have to drop to the packet level.  I was hoping to find an open source HTTP/HTTPS proxy package that would allow me to proxy a connection from one host to the other with an authorization step in the middle.

Comment: @Allen As I understand your task, you need not a regular proxy, but some packet broker that will accept two incoming connections and make a bridge between them. The problem here is that when you have an outgoing socket connection (on the client), most SSL/TLS implementations assume that this is a client side of SSL as well, and you will end up having two clients. To have a server on outgoing connection you'd need some customized SSL implementation (like ours ;). To summarize: I doubt that you will end up with just an open-source proxy - the task is too specific.

Comment: Mayevski: Under OpenSSL, having an SSL server on a network-layer outgoing connection is quite easy - you simply call `SSL_accept()` after `connect()`.